# How to use the diff() function in pandas but enter the difference values in a new column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, diff, difference

I have a dataframe df:

df

```
      x-value 
frame 
    1     15  
    2     20 
    3     19
```

How can I get:

df

```
      x-value   delta-x 
frame 
    1     15      0
    2     20      5
    3     19     -1
```

Comment: `df['delta-x']=df['x-value'].diff().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 4):

Not to say there is anything wrong with what @Wen posted as a comment, but I want to post a more complete answer.

**The Problem**
There are 3 things going on that need to be addressed:

1. Calculating the values that are the differences from one row to the next.
2. Handling the fact that the "difference" will be one less value than the original length of the dataframe and we'll have to fill in a value for the missing bit.
3. How do we assign this to a new column.

---

**Option #1**
The most natural way to do the `diff` would be to use `pd.Series.diff` (as @Wen suggested). But in order to produce the stated results, which are integers, I recommend using the `pd.Series.fillna` parameter, `downcast='infer'`.  Finally, I don't like editing the dataframe unless there is a need for it.  So I use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to produce a new dataframe that is a copy of the old one with a new column associated.

```
df.assign(**{'delta-x': df['x-value'].diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer')})

       x-value  delta-x
frame                  
1           15        0
2           20        5
3           19       -1
```

---

**Option #2**

Similar to #1 but I'll use `numpy.diff` to preserve `int` type in addition to picking up some performance.

```
df.assign(**{'delta-x': np.append(0, np.diff(df['x-value'].values))})

       x-value  delta-x
frame                  
1           15        0
2           20        5
3           19       -1
```

---

**Testing**

```
pir1 = lambda d: d.assign(**{'delta-x': d['x-value'].diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer')})
pir2 = lambda d: d.assign(**{'delta-x': np.append(0, np.diff(d['x-value'].values))})

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    columns=['pir1', 'pir2'], dtype=float)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=1000)

res.plot(loglog=True)

res.div(res.min(1), 0)
```

[image]

```
           pir1  pir2
10     2.069498   1.0
300    2.123017   1.0
1000   2.397373   1.0
3000   2.804214   1.0
10000  4.559525   1.0
30000  7.058344   1.0
```

Comment: Happy New Year ;)

Comment: @jezrael to you as well!